# How To Iteratively Add Button Callbacks in Open3d?

Tags: python, user-interface, dynamic, callback, open3d

I'm using open3d in Python to visualize 3D models with a GUI. The GUI is built with open3ds provided visualization.gui class. I am trying to add a variable number of buttons to the page depending on some data that I read in from a .txt file. I generate the buttons like so and it they look fine visually:

```
for name in button_names:
   button = gui.Button(name)
   button.set_on_clicked(lambda: self.sensor_button_click(name))
   buttons.add_child(button)
self.button_stack.pop_widget()
self.button_stack.push_widget(sensors)
```

The button_stack is a WidgetStack object which displays the top widget. This way I can change the set of buttons I display if I load in new data.

However the problem is with this line:

```
button.set_on_clicked(lambda: self.sensor_button_click(name))
```

When the users click the button I want to display some data that corresponds to each specific button, so I need the name of the button to fetch the data. However, when I do this, no matter which button I click it always acts as if I clicked the LAST button created by the for loop. Is there a way to get around this or perhaps a different approach I can use?
It's very important for this project that each button is generated based on the data I have, and that each button is linked to a specific subset of that data. If there's no way to pass which button was pressed to this callback then that will be a major issue.

Here is the callback function in case that helps:

```
 def sensor_button_click(self, button_name):
        em = self.window.theme.font_size

        dialog = gui.Dialog("Object Options")

        button_grid = gui.Vert(em, gui.Margins(em, em, em, em))
        func_buttons = gui.Horiz(em, gui.Margins(em, em, em, em))
        # Add text to popup
        popup_label = gui.Label("What would you like to do with object " + button_name + "?")
        button_grid.add_child(popup_label)

        # Add functional buttons to popup
        highlight_button = gui.Button("Highlight This Object")
        highlight_button.set_on_clicked(self.popup_highlight_click)
        data_button = gui.Button("View Object Data")
        data_button.set_on_clicked(self.popup_data_click)
        cancel_button = gui.Button("Cancel")
        cancel_button.set_on_clicked(self.popup_cancel_click)
        func_buttons.add_child(highlight_button)
        func_buttons.add_child(data_button)
        button_grid.add_child(func_buttons)
        
        # Add cancel button to popup
        # Format cancel button so it doesn't extend the full length of the dialog popup 
        h = gui.Horiz()
        h.add_stretch()
        h.add_child(cancel_button)
        h.add_stretch()
        button_grid.add_child(h)
        
        dialog.add_child(button_grid)

        self.window.show_dialog(dialog)
```